# Get android debugging to work on Ubuntu 11.04 Natty

Tags: android, adb, ubuntu-11.04

I put a file named "70-android.rules"
in

/etc/udev/rules.d/

with

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{22b8}=="22b8", MODE="0666"

but it still wont read my Motorola Atrix, is there something I'm doing wrong? most of the guides I found where for 10.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.04 needed slightly different way of doing things.

XDA thread [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=11823740) explains it step by step for 11.04 and 10.10

Answer (score 1):

Just to rule out anything really simple, did you enable USB debugging on your phone?

Comment: Have you already looked through Google's [guide on it](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)? For example, one thing I noticed is that this guide says to create a file named "51-android.rules". I'm not actually sure if the 51 means anything significant though.

Comment: @GiantMarsmallow those are for much older versions of Ubuntu, other guides I found on 10.10 say to use 70 instead of 51

Comment: Hmm...then I'm not sure what to say, since I haven't really done much with Android on Linux. +1 to give you a bit more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Change the SYSFS tag to ATTRS, works for me. Apparently they've changed the syntax. This is what mine looks like:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4"
MODE="0666"
GROUP="plugdev"
```

Of course you keep your current idVendor value, as mine is for HTC.
Hope this helps!