# Udev rules for running android app from ubuntu 11.04

Tags: android, ubuntu-11.04, udev

I'm trying to be able to run my mobile app on my android phone, and I can't get the udev rules to work no matter what I do. I'm using ubuntu 11.04 64 bit

Since the rules on the official android site are old, I had to go to the internet. I used the rules presented here:

[Get android debugging to work on Ubuntu 11.04 Natty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6702765/get-android-debugging-to-work-on-ubuntu-11-04-natty)

I went to the site linked:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=11823740

I'm sure that jdk is working fine since

```
  java -version
```

results in

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.6) (6b22-1.10.6-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)
```

I added adb to my PATH so if I type in adb I get a bunch of commands.

I downloaded the android SDK and NDK.

So, I tried to edit my udev rules for my android phone. If I type in `lsusb` then I see:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04e8:689e Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
```

I edit the udev rules using `sudo vim etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules` and I write this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8:689e", SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0666" GROUP="plugdev"
TEST=="/var/run/ConsoleKit/database", \
RUN+="udev-acl --action=$env{action} --device=$env{DEVNAME}"
```

I then entered the command `sudo chmod a+rx /etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules` then I typed in `sudo restart udev` and then I typed in `adb kill-server` and then I typed in `nohup adb start-server`.

And finally, `adb devices`, but my phone is still not recognized.

Any help would be greatly appreciated since I'm completely stumped.

Oh, and I also opened and closed my terminal window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I restarted my computer and it worked. >.<

I guess it's always something simple.

Comment: The proper command after creating a new rule is usually `sudo udevadvm control --reload-rules` (though on some older systems the option is not --reload-rules but something similar).